# Mutt: unset previously set macro when switching between accounts

Tags: mutt

I have a multi-account Mutt configuration. For a specific account, I have set two macros to switch between sender identities:

```
macro compose o "<edit-from><kill-line>Name1 <name1@domain><enter><edit-bcc><kill-line><enter>"
macro compose O "<edit-from><kill-line>Name2 <name2@domain><enter><edit-bcc><kill-line>bcc@domain<enter>"
```

How do I *unset* these macros when switching to a different account?

I have tried `unset macro o` and `set macro o ""`, but neither works (Mutt complains about config errors).

If unsetting a previously set macro is not possible, is there a "do nothing" command that I could use in `set macro o "<???>"`?

Similarly, it might be useful to know whether it is possible (and if so, how) to unset a previously set `send-hook`.

Thanks.

Comment: multi-account ? each one of them associated to one single user ?

Comment: See, e.g., [here](https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/9456162) for what I mean by multi-account setup. The identities are then dealt with via `send-hook`s, the mentioned macros, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike neomutt, mutt do not have the `unmacro` command. However you can redefine macro e.g. with empty command:

```
macro compose o '<enter-command><enter>'
```

Comment: Great, thank you! This is much better than my workaround utilising the sequence '<edit-from><enter>'.